# Is there a better way to select a boolean from a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select results from a table and the `visible` column should be a boolean ('true' or 'false' strings). Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT fldid AS "id",
       TRIM(fldlabel) AS "name",
       DECODE((select 'T' from dual where fldid in (53,54,7)), 'T', 'true', 'false') AS "visible"
  FROM fieldTable
 WHERE fldActive = 1
```

The set of `fldid`s that should be visible will be an input parameter, but for the sake of this query they are hard-coded.

Without using DECODE I would get nulls for the records that are not in the set.
Is DECODE the best solution for Oracle or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `decode` in Oracle.  The SQL standard is the `case` statement, and you do not need the subquery:

```
SELECT fldid AS "id",
       TRIM(fldlabel) AS "name",
       (case when fldid in (53, 54, 7) then 'true' else 'false' end) as visible
FROM fieldTable
WHERE fldActive = 1;
```

Comment: This reads much better than what I was doing. I was trying to use `IN` but couldn't figure out how to use it without `WHERE`. But of course, the `CASE` statement. Thanks!